# Woocommece category and shop page issue

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce, wordpress-theming

On this Woocommerce [website](https://www.globalspadevelopment.com/shop/), I have some issues:

- **1st issue**: when I add or change category in shop page and then press update button then blank page show.
- **2nd issue**: is my shop page design problem. each row show double images show in column.

Any one could tell about those issues?

Comment: are you using any plugins related to product ? OR have you uploaded multiple images to product ?

Comment: @melvin yes i try to use plugin Product Grid/List Design. but plugin not effect on theme.

Comment: It can be probably due to any plugins or some code you added. Can you switch theme to storefront and check if issue persists?

Comment: @melvin ok i try to switch and then check

Comment: Ok. let me know if the issue is solved

Comment: @melvin issue resolved on switch theme but i need my original theme

Comment: The issue is in your theme. If you have purchased the theme then you have to contact the theme support to resolve the issue. OR you can check if you have option to show multilple product images in theme customizer

Comment: @melvin actually i customize this theme but now i have to add woocommerce plugin.

Comment: You don't have woocommerce installed ? So you made shop page using  ???

Comment: @i installed woocommerce and then import woocommerce pages cart, checkout,shop

Comment: The issue is clearly with theme because when you switched to storefront the issue is solved. Which theme are you using ?

Comment: i told you this theme is develop from scratch.

Comment: Then check theme code for the issue. You have added something that caused the issue

Comment: @melvin may be. :(

Comment: Sorry. I cannot be of more help without seeing the code

Comment: @melvin do you have skype?

Comment: sorry. I don't have

Comment: @melvin ok.....